# Laravel update json column in postgresql

Tags: json, laravel, postgresql

In postgresql db I have a column type json call it "activities". I would like to add there new (key -> value) pair. Without delete existing data.

At this moment my code look like this:

```
$user = User::with('userLife')->where(['id' =>$id])->first();
    $user->userLife->confirmation_token = null;
    $user->userLife->activities = ['emailConfirmed' => Carbon::now()->timestamp];
    $user->email_confirmed = true;
    $user->push();
```

In my Model I added:

```
protected $casts = [
        'activities' => 'array',
    ];
```

But when I use this code all other data in column is removed and only 'emailConfirmed' appeared there.

So how to do it properly to just add new value in column without removing previous? 
Thank you.

Comment: you could do something like this:
$activities = $user->userLife->activities;
$activities['new_key'] = 'new_value';
$user->userLife->activities = $activities;
$user->save();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add it as new element through another variable:

```
$activities = $user->userLife->activities;

$activities['emailConfirmed'] = Carbon::now()->timestamp;

$user->userLife->activities = $activities;
```

Comment: "[] operator not supported for strings" any idea why "activities" is not cast as array?